# Success ain't all it's cracked up to be,

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

Explain, please. What does it mean. Meanings of 'ain't', 'cracked up', whole meaning and the sentence structure.

> Of course, success ain't all it's **cracked up** to be, now.

Comment: Please share your research and provide more details, as we explain in our [Details, Please... meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cracked up** is a colloquialism for "claimed" or "said".

**ain't** is non-standard for "isn't".

"Success is not everything it is said to be".

In other words, when people talk about how wonderful "success" is, they are exaggerating.   It's all "hype".

> That luxury car isn't all it's cracked up to be.  It's quite unreliable and it is very expensive to repair.